# How to use QML Repeater for page indicator?

Tags: qml, repeater

Below is part of my code. It's working fine, however I spent a lot of time trying to solve it with Repeater to be more elegant and flexible, but couldn't.

Could you please suggest a solution to me? The `areaMachine` is in an other qml file.

```
Row {
        id: pageIndicatorBoxes
        anchors.centerIn: pageIndicatorLine
        spacing: 5

        Rectangle {
            id: pageIndicatorBox1
            width: 10
            height: 10
            color: areaMachine.page == 1 ? "#e5e5e5" : "#404040"
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: pageIndicatorBox2
            width: 10
            height: 10
            color: areaMachine.page == 2 ? "#e5e5e5" : "#404040"
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: pageIndicatorBox3
            width: 10
            height: 10
            color: areaMachine.page == 3 ? "#e5e5e5" : "#404040"
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: pageIndicatorBox4
            width: 10
            height: 10
            color: areaMachine.page == 4 ? "#e5e5e5" : "#404040"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you haven't look into the documentation about [`Repeater`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html) and its main [`delegate` property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html#delegate-prop). There you can find code examples that fits your problem, so you can combine it and have something like:

```
  Row {
    id: pageIndicatorBoxes
    anchors.centerIn: pageIndicatorLine
    spacing: 5
    
    Repeater {
      model: 4
      Rectangle {
        id: pageIndicatorBox1
        width: 10
        height: 10
        color: (areaMachine.page === (index + 1)) ? "#e5e5e5" : "#404040"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I did and I tried it with several functions/variations. Just not this 'simplestestest' approach. :S Thanks.

Comment: Great to hear it helps. You can mark it as an answer then. For a further development I can advice you to have a separate as-simple-as-possible-application where you can try new components/concepts and then -> apply your results into real application you are working on.

Comment: The only thing to correct is: I need (index + 1).

Comment: Sure thing. Updated an answer.